# Optimizing Boolean Compares Between Arrays with Python

Tags: python, optimization, numpy, boolean-logic, slice

I've got some Python code I'm trying to optimize. It deals with two 2D arrays of identical size (their size can be arbitrary).  The first array is full of arbitrary Boolean values, and the second is full of semi-random numbers between 0 and 1.

What I'm trying to do is change the binary values based on the values in the modifier array.  Here's a code snippet that works just fine and encapsulates what I'm trying to do within two for-loops:

```
import numpy as np
xdim = 3
ydim = 4
binaries = np.greater(np.random.rand(xdim,ydim), 0.5)
modifier = np.random.rand(xdim,ydim)

for i in range(binaries.shape[0]):
    for j in range(binaries.shape[1]):
        if np.greater(modifier[i,j], 0.2):
            binaries[i,j] = False
```

My question: is there a better (or more proper)  way to do this?  I'd rather use things like slices instead of nested for loops, but the comparisons and Boolean logic make me think that this might be the best way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
binaries &= ~(modifier > 0.2)
```

`modifiler > 0.2` create a binary array, `~` operator does boolean not, and `&=` does boolean `and`.

**NOTE** `~` `&=` are bitwise operators, but you can use them as boolean operators.

Comment: Nice. Thanks.  I didn't know about the &= operator.

Comment: +1 I thought it would be faster to assign `False` to items meeting the condition, i.e. 'binaries[modifier > 0.2] = False`, than `&`-ing both arrays, but your answer is about 10x faster. It's of course a little faster if you do `binaries &= modifier <= 0.2`.